# Can't find 68GB local backup folder (regular backups on an external hard drive)

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, backup

A few days ago my local hard drive shows 68 GB of backups.
[image: screenShot]
 I regularly backup with time machine on an external disk and even after running a backup these file stayed.
I tired using SupaView and DaisyDisk to look at the files but both do not have access even while using then as an admin. Therefore I don't even know where this folder is or what i contains.
I have OSX El Captain (10.11.6)

Has anyone had the same issue or know what and where this folder is?

Comment: In DaisyDisk, when scanning your drive as admin, do you see 68+ GB of "hidden space?"

Comment: @SkeletonBow yes it's marked as hidden space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely your [Local Time Machine Snapshots](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015).

In Sierra, these are stored in `/.MobileBackups/Computer`, but it's not advisable to manipulate this folder directly. Either use the Time Machine application to delete individual snapshots, or disable local snapshots altogether by running the following Terminal command:

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

I can't say why MacOS isn't cleaning them up after you've run an external Time Machine backup. EDIT: On my MacBook Pro, I also see some old backups that pre-date my last external backup.

Comment: I haven't updated to Sierra yet I have El Captain (10.11.6)

Comment: I forget if they're stored in the same place on El Capitan. You may also find the backups in /Volumes/MobileBackups, but I'm not sure if that only appears while the local backup is actually happening.

Comment: I found the files. My new problem is finding out what size they are. I found one folder from before my last backup.

Comment: If you don't mind using the terminal, you can use the command `sudo du -ch /.MobileBackups` (if that's where you found them). You'll need to enter your password to run it. The very last line of the output will show you the size of all the backups, combined.

Comment: Thank you that worked. I found out that the file from before the last backup has 61GB. I'll try another backup and when that does not get rid of it i might have to delete that folder